# Python-Read and convert the list as an array (2 columns x 6 lines)

Tags: python, arrays, list, matrix

```
onelist = [[3600,3600],[1000,10000],[30,90],[0,20],[20.00,95.00],["DEMO","DEMO"]]
```

Objective: 1 -Write to a file the above list. 
2 - Read it back
3 - and let it equal in a list2

Comment: That ***is*** a list. Do you mean a list of lists? (Actually I suppose it's a list of strings as the only element of an outer list)

Comment: This is already a list of strings.  What do you expect for a result?
http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: `my_list = my_list[0]`

Comment: Python proper does not have an "array" structure.  Do you perhaps want to convert this to a NumPy ndarray?

Comment: correction the list  = [[3600,3600],[1000,10000],[30,90],[0,20],[20.00,95.00],["DEMO","DEMO"]]

Comment: for result i expect a two column table as for MIN x MAX parameters

Comment: What's the question? What part of the problem are you struggling with?

Answer (score 0):

You need to *transpose* your list of lists with `zip`:

```
l = [[3600,3600],[1000,10000],[30,90],[0,20],[20.00,95.00],["DEMO","DEMO"]]

zipped = list(zip(*l)) # make rows into columns and columns into rows
print(zipped)
print(zipped[0])
print(zipped[1])
```

Output:

```
[(3600, 1000, 30, 0, 20.0, 'DEMO'), (3600, 10000, 90, 20, 95.0, 'DEMO')
(3600, 1000, 30, 0, 20.0, 'DEMO')
(3600, 10000, 90, 20, 95.0, 'DEMO')
```

If you want sublists and not tuples you can map to list:

```
 zipped = list(map(list,zip(*l)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to read back the way i want it using:
onelist = [[3600,3600],[1000,10000],[30,90],[0,20],[20.00,95.00],["DEMO","DEMO"]]

**kl=list(onelist)**

and then using double for loop to asign variables
Thanks for help.

Answer (score -2):

```
import itertools

my_list = [[3600,3600],[1000,10000],[30,90],[0,20],[20.00,95.00],["DEMO","DEMO"]]
my_list = list(itertools.chain(*my_list))
# [3600, 3600, 1000, 10000, 30, 90, 0, 20, 20.0, 95.0, 'DEMO', 'DEMO']
```